# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 9: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have the following *sh* file:

```
#!/bin/bash

python <py_filename>.py
```

The file *filename.py* begins with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
```

and contains a list of strings with special characters like *ã* and *ç*.

When I do

`sh <sh_filename>.sh`

The following error is returned:

`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 9: invalid continuation byte`

and I can see that, for instance, the word 'Ações' is represented as 'A��es'.

I understand that is something related to file encoding but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: My guess is that it's encoding 'iso-8859-1' also known as 'latin_1'.

Comment: Most text editors will tell you in the bottom status bar what encoding is being used.  Try opening your file in a text editor and see what it says.  Then find the [Python spelling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) of that encoding.

Comment: In iso-8859-1 0xe1 is 'á     LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE' - Is that what's in position 9?

Comment: `#coding: utf-8` declares the encoding of the source file.  The `SyntaxError` indicates the source file is not saved in UTF-8.  Open the file in an editor and re-save it with UTF-8, or declare the correct encoding at the top.